# Updating FLS on a custom object

Tags: configuration

When i try to update FLS for two newly added fields
it gives me following error

> Please fix the following:
>
> Permission Activate Orders depends on permission(s): Edit Orders, Read
>   Orders

Is this something related to my permissions.I dont have access to update CRUD/FLS of custom profiles

I am system admin in my org.

Comment: How can you be a system admin in your org, but not have access to update CRUD/FLS of custom profiles? That is not possible, I think ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good doc (https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_orders_cheatsheet.pdf) (page 2) that shows that you should probably take a look at your permission set to make sure it is configured correctly and not blocking any permissions:

**Assign Order Permissions**
By default, the standard Contract Manager, Marketing User, Read Only, Solution Manager, Standard User,

**Best Practices**
• Add these new permissions to permission sets, and assign them to the appropriate users.
• Update your profiles or permission sets so that the Orders tab is visible to the appropriate users.
and System Administrator profiles contain the following new order permissions.

**Activate Orders**
Allows a user to activate orders.

**Edit Activated Orders**
Allows a user to edit orders, even if they’ve been activated, as well as deactivate orders. If a user doesn’t have this permission but has “Edit” on orders, the user can change orders only if they aren’t activated.

**Create Reduction Orders**
Allows a user to reduce orders that are activated.

**User Permissions on Orders**
Consider which users should be allowed to read, create, edit, and delete orders. Then revise their
permissions as needed in the user profiles and permission sets. If you remove a user’s “Read” permission on orders, the user won’t see any orders, order fields, or Orders related lists in Salesforce.

Some permissions automatically enable other permissions.
Users with these permissions... Automatically get these permissions...

- “Activate Orders” **get** “Read” and “Edit” on orders
- “Edit Activated Orders”  **get** “Read” and “Edit” on orders AND “Activate Orders”
- “Create Reduction Orders” **get** “Read” and “Edit” on orders